# Get two dimensions of a three dimensional array C#

Tags: java, c#, .net

In java I could do it like this:

```
Square[][][] sheets;
public final Square[][] getSheet(int index) {
    return sheets[index];
}
```

What is the equivalent in c#? Since the syntax for multidimensional arrays is a little different:

```
Square[,,] Sheets;
public Square[,] GetSheet(int index) {
    return ????
}
```

Comment: Technically, that isn't a multidimensional array in java, that's an array of arrays.  You can do the same in C#.

Comment: `int[,,] array3D = new int[x, y, z];` is a 3d array in c#

Comment: It does not make sense to take 2 dimensions of 3d array(not talking about jagged array, they are 1d). You have to specify which dimensions? XY? XZ? YZ?

Comment: sheet index and x,y, so I suppose the best way to go about it would be: `[][,]`

Comment: @VincasStonys I agree - if you are _really_ modelling an array of 2-D arrays then `Square[][,]` may be the cleanest structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent in C# is the same if you are using *jagged* arrays:

```
private Square[][][] sheets;
public Square[][] GetSheet(int index) 
{
    return sheets[index];
}
```

If you have a multi-dimensional array there's not a simple way to get two of the three dimensions.  The best you can do is *recreate* an array:

```
private Square[,,] sheets;
public Square[,] GetSheet(int index) 
{
    int x = sheets.GetLength(0);      
    int y = sheets.GetLength(1); 

    Square[,] sheet = new Square[x,y];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
         sheet[i,j] = sheets[i,z,index];

    return sheet;
}
```

> How do I initialize a `Square[4][4][4]`?

You can either loop and initialize each dimension:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    sheets[i] = new Square[4][];
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        sheets[i][j] = new Square[4];
    }
}
```

(Note that if `Square` is a reference type, then you *also* need to initialize each `Square[i][j][k]` to a value, otherwise it will be `null`)

or use array initialization syntax;

```
sheets = new Square[4][][]
{
     new Square[4][] {new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4],},
     new Square[4][] {new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4],},
     new Square[4][] {new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4],},
     new Square[4][] {new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4], new Square[4],},
};
```

Obviously, looping scales much more easily that initialization syntax.

Comment: ...or `Square[][,] sheets` if OP does not need to further project his squares.

Comment: I'm not tied to multi-dimensional arrays, so using jagged are fine.
What is the correct way then to rewrite this from java to c#: `Sheets = new Square[4][4][4];` ? 
Is it: `Sheets = new Square[4][][];` ?

Comment: @VincasStonys That's the first step. you then need to loop and  initialize each dimension (`sheets[i] = new int[4][]; sheets[i][j] = new int[4];`)